# How to resolve Stale element while looping through all the buttons?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, xpath, css-selectors

As a part of a larger test, I have to click a particular button with no assigned ID. After browsing and trying various other solutions on stackoverflow, I thought to simply loop through all the buttons - and later think about how to select it individually and click it. Here's the code:

```
    List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-primary"));
    for (WebElement b:buttons) {
        System.out.println(b.getTagName());
        System.out.println(b.getText());
    }
```

The button is dynamically generated using Jquery. The actual webpage is only a collection of .js references. Here's the code I got from Inspect Element:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bb-handler="yes">Task Status</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bb-handler="danger">Close</button>
</div>
```

There are over 20 buttons (hardly 4-5 visible at this stage) in the process on this web page. Currently, there's a popup (background is faded) with two buttons as shown in the code section above.

In selenium, it is throwing **`StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`** on the line that says `b.getTagName()`.

Unsure about what might be causing this. Already tried:
1. Implicitly waiting for 30 seconds.
2. `XPath` selectors
3. Polling multiple times in a loop and try-catch blocks 
... as mentioned in other answers. Getting same exception for all the possible solutions.

What might be causing this?

p.s. Can't share screenshot as this is a propriety enterprise application.

Comment: Have you tried explicit wait? like `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait.until()` with `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable()`

Comment: can You do like this: driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='btn btn-primary' and @ data-bb-handler ='yes']") for "Task Status" button?

Could you show more HTML, maybe there is a way how to catch the element(s) You need?

Comment: Can you share the code for : Polling multiple times in a loop and try-catch blocks? I think it should work!

Comment: @MadhavCp Can you update the question with your exact _usecase_ where you need to `getTagName()` and `getText()` of `buttons`?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to put it in a try-catch block, catch the StaleElementReferenceException and do nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the responses. I could observe that the problem is getting resolved after keying the Xpath as //*[@class='btn btn-primary'][1] the only issue is it is taking more time to load the page after clicking on the button.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp):

> A stale element reference exception is thrown in one of two cases, the
>   first being more common than the second:
>
> - The element has been deleted entirely.
> - The element is no longer
>     attached to the DOM.

These are the common causes that could cause this exception.

In your question there aren't a lot of informations but, considering what you wrote, it seems that you are:

- getting the references of all the elements with css selector **".btn.btn-primary"**
- performing some operations (that change the DOM)
- and after trying to interact with the previous references.

If you do that, you need to relocate the elements `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-primary"))` when you are trying to get the tagname/text.